# преобразование строки в коллекцию

Tags: dart

В языке **Kotlin** для преобразования строки в коллекцию нужно вначале преобразовать строку в массив, а затем в коллекцию.

```
val str: String = "Hello World!"

//из строки в массив
var ara1 : CharArray = str.toCharArray()

//пустая коллекция
var ara2: ArrayList<Char> = arrayListOf()

//из массива в коллекцию
ara1.toCollection(ara2)

//вывод на консоль
for(value in ara2) {
 print("$value ")
}
```

Как в языке **Dart** преобразовать строку в коллекцию? Есть ли такая функция? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Dart все намного легче (Попробовать можно в [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)):

```
void main() {
  String str = "Hello World!";
  List<String> list = str.split('').toList();

  print(list);

  for(String c in list){
    print(c);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, l, d, !]
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
!
```

---

В данном случае `.toList()` не обязательный)

Comment: Уважаемый MiT! Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @Anton всегда пожалуйста!)